# Calculating diminishing number of days in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to figure out how to forecast out how long it will take for a process to catch up.  The process takes 26 days to process 30 days worth of data.  It runs on day 1 with processing the data that finished most recently when it started back to up to 30 days prior.  Once this process completes, it runs again, pulling the next batch of up to 30 days prior to the current execution time, that it hasn't already processed.

1st run:  30 days of data, completes in 26 days
2nd run:  Since only 26 days of unprocessed data now exist, runs until it processes this 26 days of data
...  So on, until it is caught up and can process the most recent job within 1 day.

Here's a copy of the values I've calculated so far, although not sure if they are completely right and I'm sure there's a much better way to calculate this more dynamically.

- A2=30/26
- B column is just a cumulation of A2
- C5 = A5 - 30
- Rest of C column = Cell above it + $A$2
- D Column:  =IF(C6>A6,"Yes","No")

According to the above calculations, it wouldn't get caught up until 7/16/18.

There has to be a MUCH better way to calculate this out!

[image: Rough, working Excel values]

Comment: Try =DateDiff(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this in a different way, using one assumption about the time necessary to process a given number of days' worth of data.

The assumption is that the time required is proportional to the amount of data.  In other words, if it takes 26 days to process 30 days' worth of data, it would take only 13 days to process 15 days' worth of data.

So if the first run takes 26 days (and leaves 26 days' worth of data to be processed), the second run should take 26/30 as long.  This process repeats, and the table below shows the time required for subsequent runs.

The formula in B3 is:  `=B2*26/30`.  This is filled down until the time for a run is less than one day.

As shown in the last row, Run 24 takes less than 1 day, and the process is "caught up".  The total time for all the runs is 188.7 days.  If a run can't start on the same day that the previous run ended, you may want to round up each run's time before totaling.

[image]

To calculate the "catch up" date, use `=TODAY()+188.7`.  I get 6/24/18

Comment: I really like and appreciate the simplicity of your solution.  In reality, the actual, ongoing dates aren't really as significant.  A 3rd column could easily calculate out the date of each run, if desired.  Really, the only change I made to your formula was changing the formula in B3 to "=IF(B2>=1,B2*$B$2/30,0)", which just makes it a little more dynamic.

Comment: Glad to help.  I'm thinking the process might actually be "caught up" at the end of Run 23, since every run after that takes less than 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

Every day, it complete 30/26 days, but one day passes. So the the net gain is [(30/26)-1] days each day. That works out to it getting an extra 4/26th of a day every day. That means it takes 26/4 days to catch up one day. To catch up 30 days, it needs 30*(26/4) days. We can cancel out to get 30*13/2, then cancel out again to get 15*13, which is 195.

There are several complications to this calculation, however. For instance, if you consider the process to be "caught up" when the backlog is less than one day, as Bandersnatch's answer seems to do, my answer will overestimate the required time. On other hand, if each iteration has to be an integer number of days, then  this will underestimate it. Etc.

This is the same basic principle as the one behind the solution of the bee puzzle: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwoTrainsPuzzle.html

Comment: Or [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54695/three-points-travel-along-a-straight-line " ").

Comment: What I've realized that Batch Process days are 30 and actual process time is 26 days, write? So could you please tell me what you are trying  to FORECAST, since the sample data describes difference of 30 days in Column C !! Since the Query is number of Diminishing days?